# Android Widget is what i am Developing, By default should get displayed on Home screen

Tags: android, widget, push-notification

1) I am Developing a Android application for the WIDGET, my motto is that to Show Android widget By Default on the Android Phone Home Screen when it gets installed..

i.e Install Android widget .apk -> Default Home Screen should Display widget.
(Need not to go in widgets tab and bring on Home Screen)

2) Is it possible to Push notificaiton alert comes in android Widget. When my Push Notification Comes it should show some alert in widget..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I'm pretty sure this is impossible. The way, widgets displayed is complete responsibility of launcher app and default launcher doesn't have such functionality. We tried to implement same feature in our widgets with no success. You should show instruction on how to install widget to user on first launch.

2) Define special action string in your widget provider for this. Inside method, where you receive push notification (onReceive() of GCM broadcast receiver or onHandleIntent() of Intent service if you use one) create new Intent with component name of your widget provider class and action, you defined before. Put needed data (alert message, probably) to Extras of Intent and send broadcast. You also should mention, which widget you want to update (appWidgetId)

In onReceive() method of your widget provider filter new action and update needed information on widget as usual with RemoteViews and AppWidgetManager.

Comment: Alexandar - thanks, i have worked out with second part and onrecieve now i am able to update my Widget direct from push Notification.